# Smalltalk: Checking if a method belongs to a class (or its inheritance hierarchy)

Tags: inheritance, methods, smalltalk, squeak, gnu-smalltalk

Is there a smalltalk message that will answer with a boolean value if a given method (example: passed with #aMethod) belongs to a given class (or its hierarchy)?

I want to say something like —

```
(self containsMethod:#aMethod) ifFalse:[...blah blah].
```

Obviously, containsMethod: is a placeholder for some message I hope exists. Oh, and self's superclass in this example is Object. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, Squeak's [Method Finder](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/1916) has a fantastic search by example feature. The query `Object new. #asString. true.` finds `#respondsTo:` and some other messages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `#respondsTo:`

```
1 respondsTo: #+.
```

and there is the class-side counter part `canUnderstand:`

```
1 class canUnderstand: #+.
Integer canUnderstand: #+.
```

Comment: Note the hierarchy-searching class-side equivalent is `#canUnderstand:`

Comment: Is there something for just the class it self? without looking in the inheritance hierarchy? I need a method to answer whether a class has a certain method or not

Comment: Sure, you can do `Integer includesSelector: #asNumber` which will return `false` since `#asNumber` is only implemented in `Number`, a superclass of `Integer`.

Comment: @camillobruni Thanks for includesSelector: I was searching for it.